# How to add a Link to the end of a video with vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

I would like to add a Link to the end of a video  with vimeo

so when the video ends the browser goes to a webpage, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I add a link in the video?](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:14827):

> 1. you cannot embed a clickable link in your video on vimeo.com. we do not allow this. you can however add a link at the end of your embedded videos. **you can do this via the video settings page embedding.**
> 2. please do not forget that vimeo policy does not allow uploading videos with commercial intent as per our terms of service.

Comment: ok that looks good but is there a way to automatically go to a new page?

Comment: As I know, it is impossible. Have you ever seen videos on Vimeo with such automatical redirect? Could you show me example of it?